# Imprimir matriz multi-dimensional em Python

Tags: python

Estou com dúvida sobre como criar uma função(`imprime_matriz`) que receba uma matriz como parâmetro e imprima a matriz linha por linha. **Obs:** Os espaços após o último elemento de cada linha não devem ser impressos. Alguém pode me ajudar?

O código que tentei foi este:

```
def cria_matriz(num_linhas, num_colunas):

    matriz = []
    for i in range(num_linhas):
        linha = []
        for j in range(num_colunas):
            valor = int(input("Digite o elemento [" + str(i) + "][" + str(j) + "]"))
            linha.append(valor)

        matriz.append(linha)
    return matriz


def le_matriz():
    lin = int(input("Digite o número de linhas da matriz: "))
    col = int(input("Digite o número de colunas da matriz: "))
    return cria_matriz(lin, col)

m = le_matriz()
```

Opção 2: (mais curto)

```
def imprime_matriz(matriz):

linhas = len(matriz)
colunas = len(matriz[0])

for i in range(linhas):
    for j in range(colunas):
        if(j == colunas - 1):
            print("%d" %matriz[i][j], end = "")
        else:
            print("%d" %matriz[i][j], end = "")
print()
```

Comment: Se puder dar a dimensão da matriz ficaria melhor. Até mesmo se puder postar o código que vc tentou e a matriz que está utilizando.

Comment: @Wilker coloquei meu código na questão.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo seu código, suas matrizes serão bidimensionais, tendo em vista que é pedido a entrada do tamanho de duas dimensões apenas.
Assim pode usar o código abaixo.

```
for linha in m:
    for val in linha:
        print '{:4}'.format(val),
    print
```

Ele tem como saída.

```
Digite o numero de linhas da matriz:2
Digite o numero de colunas da matriz: 2
Digite o elemento [0][0]1
Digite o elemento [0][1]2
Digite o elemento [1][0]3
Digite o elemento [1][1]4
   1    2
   3    4
```

Pode ver o código funcionando no [ideone](https://ideone.com/LRHSb1) ou [aqui](https://repl.it/F8Gz/0).

**Note que** o código depende da dimensão da matriz, quanto mais dimensões, mais laços serão necessários.

Para imprimir matrizes **independente** da dimensão, utilize a biblioteca `NumPy`

Como no exemplo abaixo

```
import numpy as np

m1 = [[1], [2], [3]]
m2 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
print (np.matrix(m))
print
print (np.matrix(m2))
```

que gera a seguinte saída

```
[[1]
 [2]
 [3]]

[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]
```

---

**EDIT**
Adiciono abaixo imagem com saída testando os código passo e as 3 impressões de teste.

[image: Teste IDE]

.

Comment: não funcionou. deu o erro:      ***** [1.0 pontos]: testando impressao de matrizes ([[1, 2, 7], [3, 4, 8], [1, 2, 3]]) - Falhou ***** Timeout ////////// ***** [1.0 pontos]: testando impressao de matrizes ([[1, 2], [3, 4]]) - Falhou ***** Timeout //////////// [1.0 pontos]: testando impressao de matrizes ([[1], [2]]) - Falhou ***** Timeout

Comment: Qual tentativa que deu erro? Pode postar o erro que recebeu? Pois nos dois links online que postei pra vc está funcionando corretamente.

Comment: Adicionei uma imagem que mostra o teste feito aqui. Talvez vc possa estar com problema em alguma outra parte do código.

Comment: o corretor aq do curso que eu faço, não está reconhecendo esse módulo, apresenta o seguinte erro:  ***** [1.0 pontos]: testando impressao de matrizes ([[1], [2]]) - Falhou ***** ImportError: No module named 'numpy' ***** [1.0 pontos]: testando impressao de matrizes ([[1, 2], [3, 4]]) - Falhou ***** ImportError: No module named 'numpy' ***** [1.0 pontos]: testando impressao de matrizes ([[1, 2, 7], [3, 4, 8], [1, 2, 3]]) - Falhou ***** ImportError: No module named 'numpy'.  Como eu posso refazer esse código para deixa-lo mais curto e mais eficiente?

Comment: Adicione o formato da saída esperada na pergunta. Fica mais fácil para dar uma reposta ad,equada. 

Por este erro, parece que o o seu curso não tem o pacote NumPy. Assim vc terá que fazer a impressão manualmente.

Comment: consegui fazer o código mais curto, pois o outro estava me confundindo. Como faço para gerar a saída esperada, que é tipo uma tabela?

Comment: Tente especificar **exatamente** como deseja assim para assim podermos ajudar.   

A dúvida sobre como imprimir está resolvida. O problema de não ser aceito pelo validador do seu curso deve sobre a formatação do resultado final.

Comment: a minha dúvida é uma outra maneira de resolver a questão sem usar o pacote NumPy para que o validador do curso aceite.

Comment: Ali em cima te dei duas formas que vc pode utilizar para imprimir a matriz. Uma sem utilizar a biblioteca NumPy e outra utilizando. Adicione todas as informações que o curso dê acerca da questão. Como o enunciado, resultado esperado. Etc.

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde, usei seu próprio exemplo para resolver seu problema. Espero ter ajudado.

**Exemplo**

Entrada:
matriz = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

**Saída:**

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

**Função:**

```
def imprime_matriz(matriz):

    linhas = len(matriz)
    colunas = len(matriz[0])

    for i in range(linhas):
        for j in range(colunas):
            if(j == colunas - 1):
                print("%d" %matriz[i][j])
            else:
                print("%d" %matriz[i][j], end = " ")
    print()
```